# How can I use redux-form with material-ui v1 (material-ui-next)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I am a big fan of both projects but it is my first attempt to use them together. As far as I know, the only project that exists that combine the two is the [redux-form-material-ui](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui) which unfortunately for me is not compatible with material-ui-next.

Can someone refer me to an appropriate example, especially for validation and error handling? The official examples on redux-form website are also pointing to the older version of Material-UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had similar issue, found out that there is a compatible version of [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/) that is [redux-form-material-ui](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui/tree/5.0) for the [material-ui-next](https://material-ui-next.com/)

Try that..

Good Luck!